# getting error unknown property 'protocol' when using forward plugin

Tags: coredns

When using this forward

```
. {
    forward . 8.8.8.8:53 {
        protocol https_google
    }
    prometheus
    errors
    log
}
```

I am getting the error

```
Error during parsing: unknown property 'protocol'
```